# Visual studio attach to unity freezing problem

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am using VS 2015 Pro and Unity 2017.4.1f1.

When firstly attach to unity after press the play button, unity will freeze until I press the stop button in VS. After pressing the stop button, normal operation continues and vs open the "Stop debugging process" window.

But if I press the play button firstly and start the game, everything will be fine after attaching to unity. They all work well in this case.

I tried to uninstall and reinstall VS but didn't help me. What can I do in this situation?

---

> > I did fix the problem too with earlier verison (3.6.0.4) Visual Studio 2015 Tools for Unity. Everything seems normal right now.

Comment: Do you happen to have a breakpoint in which it hangs? That will freeze your unity. What happens if you press pause in the debugger while Unity is frozen?

Comment: There isn't any break point.  If press pause on VS, freezing VS to.  Need force stop with task manager on this situation.

Comment: Even if you have not inserted a breakpoint, if there is an error while VS is attached, it will break until you tell it to continue.

Comment: VS continue button in unclickable status while unity frozen.

Comment: Did you try Visual Studio 2017?

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this exact problem yesterday after installing Visual Studio 2015 and the latest Visual Studio 2015 Tools for Unity package version 3.8.0.6.  At the time I also had ReSharper installed.

After reinstalling Visual Studio 2015 without any other extensions, and installing an earlier version of the tools for unity (I had access to version 2.8.2.0), it is now working correctly again.

Comment: Thank you. I did fix the problem too with earlier verison (3.6.0.4). Everything seems normal right now.